# How to undo commit operation in SmartGit/Git

Tags: git, smartgit

Want to undo commit operation in smart git. Accidently commited wrong code and now unable to recover that code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use the reset option. So if you want to go 1 commit back in time, right-click on the commit to want to go to and click "Reset". That will COMPLETELY REMOVE any commits in front of it.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In SmartGit, just invoke **Local|Undo Last Commit**; this will put your changes back to the Index. Now you may revert them partially or all together using **Local|Discard**.

Comment: *Beware!!!* This reverts all files to versions before that commit instead of just removing the commit from Log!

Answer (score 3):

The actual `commit` command can be undone by `git reset --soft @~`

Answer (score 1):

please watch this topic : [smartgit delete commit and return to previous commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32394214/smartgit-delete-commit-and-return-to-previous-commit)

as the answer said, it's not specific to smartgit but git in general. You just have to rollback to the previous commit, create another branch and work on it !

Be careful with your following commits :)